# get value of all the drop down on change event of one drop down

Tags: angular, angular11

I am new to Angular world and I have a situation were on my html page I have 5 drop down and I want to read the values of all the 5 drop down on click event of any of the drop down so that I can apply filters on all the selected values to show data in data grid.

so my question is if this is possible with Angular or not if yes please share me some example.

app.component.html

```
    <div>  
      <table>      
        <tbody>
        <tr> 
          <td> Compnay Name :  
            <select #cmpDropDown (change) = "getChangeCompnyDetails(cmpDropDown.value, deptDropDown, prodDropDown)">
              <option [value]="cmpItem.cmpId" *ngFor = "let cmpItem of cmpResp;">{{cmpItem.cmpName}}</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td> </td>         
          <td> Department Name  
            <select #deptDropDown (change) = "getChangeDeptDetails(deptDropDown.value, cmpDropDown, prodDropDown)">
              <option [value]="deptItem.deptId" *ngFor = "let deptItem of deptResp;">{{deptItem.deptName}}</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td> </td>         
          <td> Product Name              
            <select #prodDropDown (change) = "getChangeProdDetails(prodDropDown.value, cmpDropDown, deptDropDown)">
              <option [value]="prodItem.prodId" *ngFor = "let prodItem of prodResp;" >{{prodItem.prodName}}</option>              
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>   
      </tbody>  
      </table> 
    </div>

    <div> </div>
    <!-- Show data in grid -->    
    <div>
      <table style="width:100%" border="1">  
        <thead >
          <tr> </tr> <tr> </tr>
          <tr >            
            <th scope="col">Order No</th>
            <th scope="col">ProductName</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>                      
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor = "let dataRowItem of deliveryDataResp">                       
            <td> {{dataRowItem.ordNum}}</td>
            <td> {{dataRowItem.prodName}}</td>
            <td> {{dataRowItem.status}}</td>            
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>    
  </div>
```

app.component.ts :-

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    title = 'AngularUi';  
    
    public deliveryDataResp    : any;
    public deliveryDataRespBck : any;
    public deptResp            : any = [ {"deptId": "ALL", "cmpId": "ALL", "deptName": "ALL"}];
    public prodResp            : any = [ {"prodId": "ALL", "deptId": "ALL", "prodName": "ALL"}];
        
    ngOnInit(){     

        //Get Compnay List
        let obj = this.http.get(cmpApiUrl).subscribe((cmpResp)=>{
            this.cmpResp = cmpResp;        
        })
    
        //Get delivery details 
        let deliveredObj = this.http.get(deliveredApiUrl).subscribe((deliveryDataResp)=>{
            this.deliveryDataResp = deliveryDataResp;
            this.deliveryDataRespBck = deliveryDataResp;
        })
                
    }//End of ngOnInIt

    getChangeCompnyDetails(cmpDropDownVal: String, deptDropDown: HTMLSelectElement, prodDropDown: HTMLSelectElement): void {
        
        calling department api with cmpDropDownVal, now API will give list of department associated with Company (with this call department drop down will be updated with new list of department values) 

        //As department drop down is updated with above call so now we need updated department list (how we will get updated department dropdown value ?)
        this.departmentIdSelected = this.deptResp[0].deptId;  //here I am trying to get the data from object returned by subscribe but as subscribe is async call so deptId is not accessible here hence finding way to get selceted value of department drop down so that can filter on that id
        
        this.prodIdSelected = this.prodResp[0].prodId; 
        
        this.filterDataGrid(cmpIdSelected, departmentIdSelected, prodIdSelected)
    }
    
    getChangeDeptDetails($event){
        this.deptIdSelected = event.target.value;
        
        //get product list by calling product api for deptId
    }
    
    filterDataGrid()
    {
        this.deliveryDataResp = this.deliveryDataRespBck.filter( (obj: any) => {             
            if(obj.cmpId === cmpSelVal && obj.deptId === deptSelVal && obj.prodId === prodSelVal){return true;} return false;
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful, if you provide some code with your initial tries. Some HTML &Typescript.

Comment: Have you tried with `[(ngModel)]` for each dropdown

Answer (score 0):

you need to [(ngModel)] means two way data binding for your all the dropdowns, so once you clicked then you can get the selected value of all the dropdowns within that click method with the help of variables which we have binded to all the dropdown.

Please find the below example for how we can use [(ngModel)] for dropdown and get the selected value.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
  <option *ngFor="let item of Products" [value]="item">{{item.productName}}</option>
</select>
```

you need to declare selectedValue as a variable in ts file so you will get dropdown selected value within that variable.

Hope it will help to resolve you issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the values of all the dropdowns by using Angular [Template Reference Variables][1].

Lets consider the most basic example, an HTML with 5 select tags (dropdowns):

```
<div>
  <select #select1 (change)="onChangeEventOne(select1, select2, select3, select, select5)">
    <option>Dropdown 1 - Option 1</option>
    <option>Dropdown 1 - Option 2</option>
    <option>Dropdown 1 - Option 3</option>
    <option>Dropdown 1 - Option 4</option>
    <option>Dropdown 1 - Option 5</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <select #select2 (change)="onChangeEventTwo(select1, select2, select3, select, select5)">
    <option>Dropdown 2 - Option 1</option>
    <option>Dropdown 2 - Option 2</option>
    <option>Dropdown 2 - Option 3</option>
    <option>Dropdown 2 - Option 4</option>
    <option>Dropdown 2 - Option 5</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <select #select3 (change)="onChangeEventThree(select1, select2, select3, select, select5)">
    <option>Dropdown 3 - Option 1</option>
    <option>Dropdown 3 - Option 2</option>
    <option>Dropdown 3 - Option 3</option>
    <option>Dropdown 3 - Option 4</option>
    <option>Dropdown 3 - Option 5</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <select #select4 (change)="onChangeEventFour(select1, select2, select3, select, select5)">
    <option>Dropdown 4 - Option 1</option>
    <option>Dropdown 4 - Option 2</option>
    <option>Dropdown 4 - Option 3</option>
    <option>Dropdown 4 - Option 4</option>
    <option>Dropdown 4 - Option 5</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <select #select5 (change)="onChangeEventFive(select1, select2, select3, select, select5)">
    <option>Dropdown 5 - Option 1</option>
    <option>Dropdown 5 - Option 2</option>
    <option>Dropdown 5 - Option 3</option>
    <option>Dropdown 5 - Option 4</option>
    <option>Dropdown 5 - Option 5</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Note that lines in each select:

```
#select1 (change)="onChangeEventOne(select1, select2, select3, select4, select5)"
#select2 (change)="onChangeEventTwo(select1, select2, select3, select4, select5)"
...
#select5 (change)="onChangeEventFive(select1, select2, select3, select, select5)"
```

In this case, I'm marking each select with a template variable. This provides me with a reference that I can use all across my HTML code.
Template references are identified by the `#` at their start.

Next, I'm using the `(change)` event to capture when a change occurs in any of the dropdowns.
Then I'm passing the value of each dropdown to its own function. Each function receives its own value and references each selector so that I can change them:

```js
onChangeEventOne(select1: HTMLSelectElement, select2: HTMLSelectElement, select3: HTMLSelectElement, select4: HTMLSelectElement, select5: HTMLSelectElement): void {
  if (select1.value.startsWith('a') {
    select2.value = "";
    select3.value = "";
    select4.value = "";
    select5.value = "";
  } else {
    select1.value = "";
  }
}
```

In the above example, when there is a change in the first dropdown, I pass its value as the first argument and pass the references to the other dropdowns as the next four arguments.
This allows me to set a new value for each dropdown in a more direct way.

If you want
[1]: https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables

Comment: :- Thanks for your prompt reply. Do I need to use the same function on (onChangeEvent()) ? because on change of 1st drop down I have to update values of the second drop down so I can do that in same function ?

Comment: @SwapnilM I have updated the answer to reflect your request.

Comment: really appreciated you efforts but actually on first drop down change event I am able to get the values of rest of the drop downs but I am calling API to update values of second drop down from first drop down change event so now the values of second drop down is change, is there a way I can get that updated value from first drop down change event ?

Comment: I have updated my answer to better match what I think you want to do, but I'm unsure if its this. From my understanding, you want to capture all the dropdowns, check the first and update the value of the others, you are not modifying the visible options in this case. Is it correct?

Comment: you were correct at first place, So I have two requirements 1. to get the values of the current selected values of the drop down (I am able to figure out with your first solution to use Template Reference Variables) now 2nd requirement in the same change event as **the value of the 2nd drop down is changed because of API call so I need that updated value**  Please note :- I have updated my example with your approach. So you can refer the updated question and see call from getChangeCompnyDetails()

Comment: :- Do you please help me with the same example which you have used in your example, but instated of normal dropDown can you please try to use primeNg p-dropDown.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can follow the below example I have created one in slackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bmof5o?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks Nirmalya for your reply. On change event I am also calling API to change values of lets say 2nd drop down so how will I perform API call on 1st drop down change event and how I will get updated value of 2nd drop down with rest of the drop downs value.

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to do it all manually.
You can angular reactive forms,
In your app module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In your component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      companyName: ['1'],
      departmentName: ['1'],
      productName: ['1']
    })

    this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
      this.filterData(x)
    });
  }

  filterData(data) {
    console.log(data)
    // apply filters here
  }
}
```

In your component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">

  <label>Company Name</label>
  <select formControlName="companyName">
    <option value="1">company 01</option>
    <option value="2">company 01</option>
  </select>

  <label>Department Name</label>
  <select formControlName="departmentName">
    <option value="1">department 01</option>
    <option value="2">department 02</option>
  </select>

  <label>Product Name</label>
  <select formControlName="productName">
    <option value="1">product 01</option>
    <option value="2">product 02</option>
  </select>

</form>
```

This is an example, you can update your files according to this or refer below link

https://fireship.io/lessons/basics-reactive-forms-in-angular/

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve this with ng-model and able to access the values in in .ts.